# why file can not be read in adobe flash , air or actionscript on server

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, air, flash

I used this function to load a text file

```
public function load_ways(zoom)
{
    finish_working = false;
    _zoom = zoom;
    var data:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    data.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded_KV);
    data.load(new URLRequest("zoom\\" + _zoom + ".txt"));
}
```

That worked correctly when i ran my application on my computer.
But when I moved the file to a server, the file won't load.

Actually, onLoaded_KV function was called but with empty data.

Comment: Do you manage to load manually the txt file by its URL and check its content?

Comment: If using flashPro, Make sure you've set your sandbox permission from local to network in the publish security settings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have a backslash in an URL change it to:

```
public function load_ways(zoom)
{
    finish_working = false;
    _zoom = zoom;
    var data:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    data.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded_KV);
    data.load(new URLRequest("zoom/" + _zoom + ".txt"));
}
```

Comment: he had the back slash escaped so it shouldnt matter.

Comment: @The_asMan, this is an URL, it works on his computer since it's a local path (with Windows I assume), but no backslashes on the web.